# Help with this Rails code, (select and javascript)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, select

I need to have a select with options and JavaScript in each one,

```
**select...%>**
 <% @buscar.each do |j|%>
 <option value="<%= j.cedula_tutor1 %>" onclick="Datos2('j.cedula_tutor1');">
 <%= j.cedula_tutor1 %>
</option>
<%end%>
 **</select>**
```

This is what I have made in rails:

```
<%=select("cedula_tutor1", "nombre",Tutore.all.collect{|u| [u.cedula_tutor1,u.nombre_tutor1]},{}, {:onchange => "Datos2('j.cedula_tutor1'))"})%>
```

Of course that doesn't work because the `j.cedula_tutor1` is outside the loop.  How can I make it?  I just want to call a JavaScript function giving the `j.cedula_tutor` as parameters.

Comment: in the j.cedula_tutor1 is u.cedula_tutor1, do you have any example or link where I can see what you mean please... btw thanks por reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should extend your loop with it. or just make some class variable to access it via `parent` attribute of child instance. or something like caller.